# How to push to a new project on App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, app-store, app-store-connect

My Team on App Store Connect has two apps, `A` and `B`. I've been pushing to `A`, but now my client wants me to push to `B`. In XCode I changed the Bundle ID to the one matching `B` and tried to create an archive to push, but it gave me the error `No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found: No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "F7RYPSTSCP" with a private key was found.`

How do I create this new signing certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort out the certification and provision issues.

As a starter, I would suggest that you follow this tips that I wrote for myself in the events I struggle like you and forget the steps.

https://daddycoding.com/2020/07/22/missing-private-key/

This should help you get started.